# php complex array sort to table

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following Array...

```
Array
(
    [main] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name_one] => banana
                    [name_two] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name_one] => orange
                    [name_two] => banana
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name_one] => 
                    [name_two] => orange
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name_one] => pear
                    [name_two] => 
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [name_one] => pear
                    [name_two] => mango
                )
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name_one] => 
                    [name_two] => 
                )

        )

)
```

the logic behind is the following, 
If the field "name_two" is not empty ignor "name_one" and count only "name_two".
If the field "name_two" is empty the take "name_one" and count.
If both are empty..No count.

The result from the above array should look like the following table...

```
------------------------------
category   |  total
------------------------------
banana     |    2
-----------------------------
orange     |    1
-----------------------------
pear       |    1
-----------------------------
mango      |    1
-----------------------------
Total      |    5
```

I have tried different method including foreach, for and while loop in php but no luck...How do i achieve the table above in php?

if it is easy, the array structure is changed? you are most welcome to change as you like and i can adapt it here. The main issue is generating the table from the array look like the above structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do what you want. It processes each element of the array, looking for a valid `name_two` value, or if not, then a valid `name_one` value, and increments the count of that value.

```
$counts = array();
foreach ($array['main'] as $item) {
    if (!empty($item['name_two'])) {
        @$counts[$item['name_two']]++;
    }
    elseif (!empty($item['name_one'])) {
        @$counts[$item['name_one']]++;
    }
}
foreach ($counts as $key => $count) {
    echo "$key: $count\n";
}
```

Output:

```
banana: 2
orange: 1 
pear: 1 
mango: 1
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/d6tKr)

Note I use `@` in front of the increment statements to avoid "Undefined index" errors when a name is first encountered. If you don't want to do that, you can use the ?? (NULL coalescing operator) in PHP7 e.g.

```
$counts[$item['name_two']] = ($counts[$item['name_two']] ?? 0) + 1;
```

or in PHP prior to 7

```
$counts[$item['name_two']] = (isset($counts[$item['name_two']]) ? $counts[$item['name_two']] : 0) + 1;
```